# Use AddServerSideBlazor() from inside a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to setup my own Service Collection like so:

```
public static void AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    //services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
}
```

I can't figure out how to get this running, I tried adding several NuGet References but none does work. e.g. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` to get `AddServerSideBlazor();` working.

I want to use it like this in my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMyServices();
}
```

The Error I get:

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddServerSideBlazor' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddServerSideBlazor' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

Edit:
After some more looking into it I think the correct package is
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` but adding it via NuGet gives me this error:

> The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0 has a package type
> DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Extend the IServiceCollection.

```
public static Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServerSideBlazorBuilder AddServerSideBlazor (this Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services, Action<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.CircuitOptions>? configure = default);
```

found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.componentservicecollectionextensions.addserversideblazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I retried using a Razor Class Library with Pages support, now it works. But I am not sure if it was exactly this change. Have to test this further. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I think you just need to add a reference `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to your class file containing `AddMyServices`.  That's were most of the Service Extensions live.